# Laravel: How to get selected columns of Base Table with Eager Loading?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

For example here the table structure.

```
User
-----
-id
-role_id
-fname
-lname
-country_code
-mobile
-password
-remember_token
-email
-address
-location_id
```

And Another table

```
Role
-----
-id
-name
```

Now if I want all user information from user table with role table I will write like this.

$user = User::with('Role')->where('users.id',$id)->first()->toArray();

But it will fetch all the data from user table.
What I need is selected columns of User table with eager loading.
Like only fname,lname,mobile,email from user table and role_name from role table.

I know how to select particular columns of associated table as below.

```
public function Role(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role')->select('id','name as role_name');
}
```

But how to select particular columns of User table using with() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (i write it by head, test it):

```
$user = User::with('Role')
            ->where('users.id',$id)
            ->select('users.fname','users.lname','users.mobile','users.email', 'roles.name as role_name')
            ->first()->toArray();
```

or use [joints](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins) directly.

Comment: It can't find roles.name.
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.`fname`, `users`.`lname`, `users`.`mobile`, `users`.`email`, `roles`.`name` as `role_name` from `users` where `users`.`id` = 4 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

Comment: could you show generated query by $user = User::with('Role')->where('users.id',$id)->first()->toArray();  (for this purpose use before query invocation statement DB::enableQueryLog(); , and show it by dd(DB::getQueryLog());). May be laravel do 'with' using two sql queries... (?)

Comment: It doesn't use belongs to relation defined in model. Here is the query log.

"select `users`.`fname`, `users`.`lname`, `users`.`mobile`, `users`.`email`, `roles`.`name` as `role_name` from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null"

Comment: Can you try again give me sql query generated by BE CAREFUL: $user = User::with('Role')->where('users.id',$id)->first()

Comment: Your previous query is impossible to work because you make `select user.fname,..., roles.name .. from users` so this query cannot work because roles table doesnt appear after `from` statement. So could you again give me proper SQL query from this: User::with('Role')->where('users.id',$id)->first()

Answer (score 0):

Please try this;

```
User::with(['Role' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('name');
}])->select('fname', 'lname', 'mobile', 'email', 'role_id')->whereId($id)->first()->toArray();
```

Comment: It doesn't show fetch role data.
"fname" => "John"
"lname" => "Doe"
"mobile" => "1234567890"
"email" => "johndoe@gmail.com"
"role" => null

Comment: Yes ! you need to add the role_id in user select.

Comment: Did you try the new one ?

Comment: Yes. It still doesn't fetch role_name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116863/discussion-between-ismail-rbouh-and-kavan-pancholi).